# How to access DB in asp.net on this scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Hello Guys Below is my Code for accessing database. when i try to open site from more than one tab or i open it in debugging mode it gives error!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DomeNameSpace
{
    public class DAL
    {
        public static string _ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xClassConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        public static SqlConnection _Connection = null;

        public static SqlConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {
                //_Connection.Close();
                //private static SqlConnection _Connection = null;
                if (_Connection == null)
                {
                    _Connection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
                    _Connection.Open();

                    return _Connection;
                }
                else if (_Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    _Connection.Open();

                    return _Connection;
                }
                else
                {
                    return _Connection;
                }
            }
        }

        public static DataSet GetDataSet(string sql)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection);
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                //   Connection.Close();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adp.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
            catch (SqlException err)
            {
                // Replace the error with something less specific.
                // You could also log the error now.
                throw new ApplicationException("Data error. " + err.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Connection.Close();
            }
        }

        public static DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
        {
            DataSet ds = GetDataSet(sql);

            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                return ds.Tables[0];
            return null;
        }



        public static int ExecuteSQL(string sql)
        {
            try
            {
                string BegSql = "BEGIN TRY BEGIN TRANSACTION ";
                string EndSql = " COMMIT TRANSACTION END TRY BEGIN CATCH  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION END CATCH";
                string NewSql = BegSql + sql + EndSql;
                sql = NewSql;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection);
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            finally
            {
                Connection.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But i am getting following here error
[image]

and output says

[image]

what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Why you really need to keep the connection static? you can return a connection when ever you need!! If you still need to keep static, I don't think you need to return the connection as it will be accessible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A single, static database connection is a *famously* bad idea.  It essentially makes your application single-threaded, which a web application by nature is not.

Don't centralize your connection object like this.  Creating a connection object is not a resource-intensive operation.  And opening the connection itself isn't particularly resource-intensive, the connection pool takes care of most of the heavy lifting for you and is very well optimized.

Create your database connection objects when you need them, as close to where you use them as possible, and dispose of them as soon as you're done with them.  In general, a pattern similar to this:

```
public void SomeMethodWhichConnectsToDB()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
        using (var command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            // do something with the connection, execute the command, etc
        }
}
```

You can encapsulate the *creation* of the connection into a (non-static) method to avoid code duplication and whatnot.  But don't re-use the same connection object in memory over and over.  Create it, use it, destroy it in as little time as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory but the reason you are running into this sort of problem is because the connection object is static, which means, that you are sharing this instance for all the calls you make to the database - all threads executing any kind of data access will use the same connection, which you clearly don't want.

What you should do is create the instance of a SQL Connection inside every method or create a Utility class that returns a new instance for every call.

For example:

```
public class DBUtility 
{
     public static DbConnection GetOpenConnection()
     {
          var conn = new DBConnection(connectionString); //or whatever type
          conn.Open();
          return conn;
     }
}
```

Now in your methods:

```
 public static int ExecuteSQL(string sql)
 {
      using (var conn = DBUtility.GetOpenConnection()) 
      {
           ....
      }
 }
```